# While initiating the ChromeDriver getting an exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, timeoutexception

I'm very new to Selenium. Below given is my first test script.

Question: Does it require selenium server to test a local website (which is hosted in the same machine as the test scripts being run).

Also tried executing the same script from Internet Explorer also, still getting the same.
It just opens the browser and closes(because of finally block) it.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class TestScript {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeDriver driver = null;
        try 
        { 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            System.out.println("Opening the Browser");
            driver.get("http://localhsot:5080/myWebSite/8450191#");
            System.out.println("Open the Browser");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Title" +driver.getTitle());

        }
        catch (Exception ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Quitting the Browser");
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Exception: Below is the exception I am getting while executing from the Eclipse:

```
[2820:6204:36503609:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(93)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: '01hw535163', ip: '10.72.15.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_17'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:108)
    at com.seic.scripts.TestScript.main(TestScript.java:16)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: '01hw535163', ip: '10.72.15.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_17'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:37571/status] to be available after 20009 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
    ... 10 more
Quitting the Browser
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.scripts.TestScript.main(TestScript.java:31)
```

Chrome Version: 21.0.1171.0

OS: Windows 7 64 bit.

Selenium Web Driver version:2.39.0

Comment: have you tried the code using firefox? You can remove the System.setProperty() and call driver = new FirefoxDriver() directly. I also see that the spelling of local host is wrong in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a little confused about what you need to point Selenium to.

Here:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
```

This setting, `webdriver.chrome.driver` is a setting that Selenium will read to find out where the **ChromeDriver** is located, **not** the *actual* Chrome installation.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

You must download the ChromeDriver and where it is located should be what you pass in for the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property.

I imagine it's the same reason when you try with IE, it also requires a driver which I guess you don't have:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

In terms of whether you need a "server" -> for your tests, no, you are not running them remotely. Once you decide to run them remotely (i.e use the `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `ChromeDriver`) then you will need the Selenium server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have dowloaded the ChromeDriver. Now i'm getting below exception. Please help..

Comment: Started ChromeDriver
port=2275
version=14.0.836.0
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(89): error: Value of: app_launched
  Actual: 1
Expected: AUTOMATION_SUCCESS
Which is: 0
Error while awaiting automation ping from browser process
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(223): error: Value of: automation()->GetBrowserWindowCount(&window_count)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(244): error: Value of: browser_proxy.get()
  Actual: false
Expected: true

Comment: .\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(269): error: Value of: WaitForBrowserProcessToQuit( TestTimeouts::action_max_timeout_ms(), &exit_code)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(270): error: Value of: exit_code
  Actual: -1
Expected: 0
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: C:\Users\Bnaresh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 51.73 seconds

Comment: Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: '01hw535163', ip: '10.72.15.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_17'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance

Comment: Few things, a) what version of Chrome are you using? Re-download the ChromeDriver from here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/ ...and edit your original post with the full stack trace details you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend instead of using System.setProperty() to put your drivers in the same folder and point to that folder in System Variables Path. Then you don't need to point to it at all in code and updating your driver won't require a code rewrite.